# Get data from column in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

In oracle 10g, i want to get data for the `username` and `email` columns where the table name is `HP`.

I used the following code:

```
 select rawtohex(username||chr(58)||email) from HP
```

But I get:

> ORA-00942: With error table or view does not exist

Comment: After your edit,I think you created your table with double quotes,so now you always need to refer to it using double quotes."HP"

Comment: sorry , i edited it now. when tried to add ' ', i got error with ORA-00911: invalid character. Also "HP" gave the same error (invalid character).

Comment: Do you have a table named HP?

Comment: Yes, i have it. In your opinion what is the best statement should i use to get data from these columns.

Comment: Are they in raw format?Why do you use rawtohex?

Comment: As far as I can tell rawtohex only accepts an argument,so you have to call it for each column.But this is unrelated to table not exists error.

Comment: thanks for your effort

Comment: But , are any functions can be used for this.

Comment: Call it separately and concatenate them.

Comment: Are you mean this (select username & select email ) from HP then concat(username,email)

Comment: rawtohex(col)||rawtohex(someothercol)||rawtohex(....

Comment: @Mihai i know what do you mean but i can't write it as i never used concat function before

Comment: Does you user have privilege to select on table HP?

Comment: @Guneli, how can i know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that user and table are in different schemas?
What is the output of 2 next statements:

```
select user from dual;
select owner from all_tables where table_name = 'HP';
```

Comment: No , it gave same result. Thanks